# Extracting collocates for a given word from a text corpus - Python

Tags: python, nltk, n-gram, collocation, log-likelihood

I am trying to find out how to extract the collocates of a specific word out of a text. As in: what are the words that make a statistically significant collocation with e.g. the word "hobbit" in the entire text corpus? I am expecting a result similar to a list of words (collocates ) or maybe tuples (my word + its collocate).

I know how to make bi- and tri-grams using nltk, and also how to select only the bi- or trigrams that contain my word of interest. I am using the following code (adapted from [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21165702/nltk-collocations-for-specific-words#_=_)).

```
import nltk
from nltk.collocations import *
corpus  = nltk.Text(text) # "text" is a list of tokens
trigram_measures = nltk.collocations.TrigramAssocMeasures()
tri_finder = TrigramCollocationFinder.from_words(corpus)
# Only trigrams that appear 3+ times
tri_finder.apply_freq_filter(3)
# Only the ones containing my word
my_filter = lambda *w: 'Hobbit' not in w
tri_finder.apply_ngram_filter(my_filter)

print tri_finder.nbest(trigram_measures.likelihood_ratio, 20)
```

This works fine and gives me a list of trigrams (one element of of which is my word) each with their log-likelihood value. But I don't really want to select words only from a list of trigrams. I would like to make all possible N-Gram combinations in a window of my choice (for example, all words in a window of 3 left and 3 right from my word - that would mean a 7-Gram), and then check which of those N-gram words has a statistically relevant frequency paired with my word of interest. I would like to take the Log-Likelihood value for that.

My idea would be:

1) Calculate all N-Gram combinations in different sizes containing my word (not necessarily using nltk, unless it allows to calculate units larger than trigrams, but i haven't found that option),

2) Compute the log-likelihood value for each of the words composing my N-grams, and somehow compare it against the frequency of the n-gram they appear in (?). Here is where I get lost a bit... I am not experienced in this and I don't know how to think this step.

Does anyone have suggestions how I should do? 
And assuming I use the pool of trigrams provided by nltk for now: does anyone have ideas how to proceed from there to get a list of the most relevant words near my search word?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Interesting problem ...

Related to 1) take a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17531684/n-grams-in-python-four-five-six-grams)...different nice solutions to make ngrams .. basically I lo

```
from nltk import ngrams
sentence = 'this is a foo bar sentences and i want to ngramize it'
n = 6
sixgrams = ngrams(sentence.split(), n)
for grams in sixgrams:
    print (grams)
```

The other way could be:

```
   phrases = Phrases(doc,min_count=2)
   bigram = models.phrases.Phraser(phrases)
   phrases = Phrases(bigram[doc],min_count=2)
   trigram = models.phrases.Phraser(phrases)
   phrases = Phrases(trigram[doc],min_count=2)
   Quadgram = models.phrases.Phraser(phrases)
   ... (you could continue infinitely)
```

min_count controls the frequency of each word in the corpora.

Related to 2) It's somehow tricky calculating loglikelihood for more than two variables since you should count for all the permutations. look this [thesis](http://www.d.umn.edu/~tpederse/Pubs/bridget-thesis.pdf) which guy proposed a solution (page 26 contains a good explanation).

However, in addition to log-likelihood function, there is PMI (Pointwise Mutual Information) metric which calculates the co-occurrence of pair of words divided by their individual frequency in the text. PMI is easy to understand and calculate which you could use it for each pair of the words.