# How to find bi-grams which include pre-defined words?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I know it is possible to find bigrams which have a particular word from the example in the link below:

```
finder = BigramCollocationFinder.from_words(text.split())
word_filter = lambda w1, w2: "man" not in (w1, w2)
finder.apply_ngram_filter(word_filter)

bigram_measures = nltk.collocations.BigramAssocMeasures()
raw_freq_ranking = finder.nbest(bigram_measures.raw_freq, 10) #top-10
    >>>
```

[nltk: how to get bigrams containing a specific word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49197667/nltk-how-to-get-bigrams-containing-a-specific-word)

But I am not sure how this can be applied if I need bigrams containing both words pre-defined.

Example:

My Sentence: `"hello, yesterday I have seen a man walking. On the other side there was another man yelling: "who are you, man?"`

Given a list:`["yesterday", "other", "I", "side"]` 
How can I get a list of bi-grams with the given words. i.e:
`[("yesterday", "I"), ("other", "side")]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is probably a `word_filter` function that returns `False` only if all the words in a particular bigram are part of the list

```
def word_filter(x, y):
    if x in lst and y in lst:
        return False
    return True
```

where `lst = ["yesterday", "I", "other", "side"]`

Note that this function is accessing the `lst` from the outer scope - which is a dangerous thing, so make sure you don't make any changes to `lst` within the `word_filter` function

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Mortz.
I do not want to find all combination of bigrams from the list. To be more precise, I was looking for a way to find all bigrams in a text that contains both words in the given list.

Comment: When you say "both words", do you mean you also want to consider, say, `(" yesterday ", " side")` as a valid bigram to be found?

Comment: Yes, exactly. That is what I meant.

Comment: yes, instead of using a function though I created a list of tuples with all bigrams and loop through them, checking each time if both words of the bigram are in the list of words and removing the invalid ones.

Comment: The only problem with creating a list of bigrams from your search list is that once your search list starts getting larger, it starts getting computationally expensive to create a bigrams list. Always best to use in built functions

Answer (score 0):

First you can create all possible bigrams for your vocabulary and feed that as the input for a countVectorizer, which can transform your given text into bigram counts.

Then, you filter the generated bigrams based on the counts given by countVectorizer.

Note: I have changed the token pattern to account for even single character. By default, it skips the single characters.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
import itertools

corpus = ["hello, yesterday I have seen a man walking. On the other side there was another man yelling: who are you, man?"]
unigrams=["yesterday", "other", "I", "side"]
bi_grams=[' '.join(bi_gram).lower() for bi_gram in itertools.combinations(unigrams, 2)]
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(vocabulary=bi_grams,ngram_range=(2,2),token_pattern=r"(?u)\b\w+\b")
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
print([word for count,word in zip(X.sum(0).tolist()[0],vectorizer.get_feature_names()) if count])
```

output:

```
['yesterday i', 'other side']
```

This approach would be a better approach when you have more number of documents and less number of words in the vocabulary. If its other way around, you can find all the bigrams in the document first and then filter it using your vocabulary.